# how to assign a new value to a variable inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would want the variable "turno" to change when using the function, so that the next time I call it it could execute the other part of the if-else. 
For example, when I call caca(x), the value of x remains the same the 5 times I call it, instead of switching from False to True and viceversa.

Many thanks.

```
def caca(turno):
    if turno:
        print(1)
        turno=not turno
        return turno
    else:
        print(2)
        turno=not turno
        return turno
x=False
for i in range(5):
    print(caca(x))
```

This other attempt does not work either:

```
def caca(turno):
    if turno:
        print(1)
        turno=not turno

    else:
        print(2)
        turno=not turno

x=False
for i in range(5):
    print(caca(x))
```

Comment: Just write `x = caca(x)` and then `print(x)`. Just be sure to return turno inside the function.

Comment: Names are not passed to functions; *values* are. You can't change what `x` is bound to by calling `caca(x)`.